# Android Mobile number Validation According to country code

Tags: android, validation, mobile

I have refered this [Validation for a cell number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958665/validation-for-a-cell-number-in-android), [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/123666#123666) and [check mobile number valid or not through country code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265181/check-mobile-number-valid-or-not-through-country-code) links but I could not find that how can I validate a number if I have country code.

If anyone has any idea about it then please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer below link.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765271/validate-mobile-number-with-the-country-code/44734401#44734401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using libphonenumber lib from Google.

Refer to this link https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/wiki/HowToRunJavaDemo

Hope this will help someone else. :)